# Setting twitter status from iPhone not loading

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, uiwebview

```
  -(void)shareOnTwitter:(NSString *)link{
    link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://m.twitter.com/?status=%@",link];
    //load webView etc
```

But twitter is taking me to the logon page without my link saved. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to login via OAuth first. Take a look at this: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq
Maybe you want to use [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)